# Can't address parent field in query with multiple subqueries

Tags: mysql

EDIT: Better explanation
I have a page with a job. The job as an idea and three skills (skill_ids) and skill requirements (a user must have at least this skill value to be qualified). 
I click on the job to find candidates, so I have the job_id and the three skill_ids and skill_id_requirements. So I can do this so far as the first answer proposed with joins. I find all users who have the three skills. The skills are saved in skill_ratings. So far it works as I use to find the skill_id's only.
But now I want the value and here I have my code where I compute the final value (called rating). The rating respects all given values, but isn't a simple average or the sum of all. That's why I need the long horrible code. In the long horrible code I usually insert a user's ID. But here I need all user_id's who have the skills mentioned above just to calculate if they are qualified. This is dynamic.

I'm having a table where I want to find people who are qualified for a position under some requirements. Here I work with one table called skill_ratings, but (as far as I see) need to add some subqueries. And here I have the problem. There are many subqueries and I've tried to address a parent query field. But it only seems to work in a first-grade subquery to a parent query.
Here's my structure:

```
    SELECT * FROM table t 
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table d WHERE x > 1 
    AND b=t.id 
    AND y <= (SELECT a FROM (MAIN SUBQUERY WITH CALCULATIONS)))
    GROUP BY xyx
```

But the error I get is: **#1054 - Unknown column 'skra.usr_id_get' in 'where clause'**. skra is the parent table in this case.

I want to get the following (pseudo-sql):

```
SELECT all FROM table t AS x 
WHERE EXISTS (
            SELECT all FROM table t AS y 
            WHERE y.skill_id = 1 
            AND y.usr_id_get = t.usr_id_get 
            AND y.value <= (my algorithm)
)
```

The main subquery is important so far as I want to get a computed number. Elsewhere the code works because I were able to work with predefined PHP-variables for a user's ID. But I can't do this here as I need to find the users within the boundaries of the where-clauses.

How can I solve this? Because addressing a parent-field in a subquery seems to be limited to a first-grade subquery.

EDIT: Code

```
    Code removed due to project status.
```

Error: #1054 - Unknown column 'c.usr_id_get' in 'where clause'

Comment: Your simplifying your query makes it hard to follow. What is table d, table t, table skra, table skill_ratings? Nothing seems to match. Please make your explantions, error message and sample queries match. Show us table definitions (especially primary/unique keys). Show us sample data and expected result.

Comment: Hi Thorsten,
Have edited the post and at the bottom you find the code as it exists now after Matteo's suggested change to use "JOIN". Aber danke für den Hinweis.

Comment: The query looks horrible to say the truth. Starting with the same tables getting selected again and again, and expressions like `((SELECT sv) * (SELECT grade))` which is simply `sv * grade` of course.  With `usr_id_get` being the only column used from `w`, you can remove about 75% of your query without changing the results. Can you explain precisely what the query is supposed to select? As mentioned, tell us about primary keys, show sample data and expected result. I am sure this will boil down to a rather simple query.

Comment: It's chaotic, I know. So far I tidied up the code. As for '((SELECT sv) * ...', I can't just use sv * grade as these are newly created columns and, just to be sure, theye require brackets. But I were able to delete one pair of brackets.
With the horrible query I calculate/create a value respecting some data such as connections. The final column created is rating. With the whole query I want to find all users having a skill (skill_id) and the rating associated to the skill_id equal or larger than a predefined user.
The problem is, as I see, I can't use a column-alias in a where-clause. Hard.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. So there is a job. For this job there are skills needed at a certain level. So job X may require skill A with at least level 20 and skill B with at least level 70. Now we look for all users having these skills with an appropriate level. User U1 with skills A/50, C/50 lacks skill B and is out. User U2 with skills A/50, B/50 has not enough skill B and is out. User U2 with skills A/50, B/70 is in. Yes? So which is the job_skill table? Which is the user_skill table?

Comment: Quick answer (will be off for some hours, don't be surprised): you got it (if you mean U3 instead of U2 is in). the job_values will be transmitted via click and are PHP-variables such as $job_skill1 etc. The skill_table is skill_ratings, consists of all ratings a user got. So far your idea was good with the average, just that I use Horrible Query for another calculation.
skill_ratings has id, usr_id_give, usr_id_get (who got the rating for a specific skill), skill_id, value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want users that have certain skills of certain levels. For example all users that have skill 1 with at least level 20 and skill 2 with at least level 70.

Here is an algorithm:

1. First of all we must get the skill levels. A user has several skill ratings and the average rating per skill is the level.
2. Then we want a table of criteria (skill 1 / level 20, skill 2 / level 70 in our example).
3. We collect all user skill levels that match the criteria (`EXISTS` clause) and then
4. keep the users that match all skill levels (`count(*) = <desired number of skills>`).

The query:

```
select
  sr.usr_id_get
from
(
  select usr_id_get, skill_id, avg(value) as level
  from skill_ratings
  group by usr_id_get, skill_id
) sr
where exists
(
  select *
  from
  (
    select 1 as skill_id, 20 as level
    union all
    select 2 as skill_id, 70 as level
  ) criteria 
  where sr.skill_id =  criteria.skill_id 
    and sr.level    >= criteria.level
)
group by usr_id_get
having count(*) = 2;
```

You can also make criteria a real (temporary) table. Then your query stays the same, no matter how many skills are requested. You'd have

```
where exists
(
  select *
  from criteria 
  where sr.skill_id =  criteria.skill_id 
    and sr.level    >= criteria.level
)
group by usr_id_get
having count(*) = (select count(*) from criteria);
```

then.

Comment: Works. Thank you very much. Changed it a bit to my topic, but it works. Vielen Dank, Thorsten. Der Knoten ist geplatzt. :-)

Comment: `where exists ( select * [...] )` could be simplified as `where exists ( select 1 [...] )`, it should lighten the database load in creating the temporary view.

Comment: @Matteo Tassinari: No. In an `EXISTS` clause it doesn't matter what's in your select list. Try `where exists (select 1/0)`. This doesn't raise a division by zero error as the select clause doesn't get evaluated.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: oh ok, I thought it mattered, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it could be done with a simple `JOIN`:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM your_table T
JOIN other_table Y ON (
  T.usr_id_get = Y.usr_id_get
  AND T.skill_id = 1
  AND Y.value <= [...]
)
```

If you need to perform some sort of calculations before the join, then you could join with a subquery:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM your_table T
JOIN (
  SELECT *
  FROM other_table Y
  WHERE Y.skill_id = 1
    AND Y.value = [...]
) Y USING(usr_id_get)
```

Comment: Grazie, Matteo. I'll try out. But may take some time.

Comment: that's a very helpful approach. But it doesn't solve the problem with user_id's at all as the algo in the subquery still doesn't know the column with the user_id. I've pasted the code in the post. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Matteo, thanks, have mixed your solution with Thorsten's solution. Now I have what I want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a user, say user 123, and a skill, say skill 99. Now you want to get the avarage rating for user 123 and skill 99 and then find all users with an equal or better average rating on that skill.

This is how to get the avarage ratings for skill 99 per user:

```
select usr_id_get, avg(value)
from skill_ratings
where skill_id = 99
group by usr_id_get;
```

This is how to get all users with an equal or better avarage rating for skill 99 than user 123:

```
select usr_id_get
from skill_ratings
where skill_id = 99
group by usr_id_get
having avg(value) >= 
  (select avg(value) from skill_ratings where skill_id = 99 and usr_id_get = 123);
```

Add to this whatever other criteria you need.

Comment: Thanks, Thorsten. I see that I have to improve my problem description which I did now. So far your reply is what I already know how/can do. The problem is more about replacing the numeric value of a user id with all id's of users having a specific skill and iterate to find the candidate who's column.rating value is higher than a specific number.